# How to set an animation for Fragment?

Tags: android

I want to implement an animation for a fragment on my activity.
But regular `startAnimation()` method isn't applicable to fragment.

How can I set an animation to my fragment?
The following is my snippet:

```
Fragment listview = (Fragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_tab_fragment);
final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate the adding/removing of a fragment you should use :

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimation();
```

You should have a look at [FragmentTransaction documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) .

Just be carefull and call the `setCustomAnimation()` method, before `add(fragment)` or `replace(fragment)` on your `FragmentTransaction`.

Comment: how to implement it with the snippet I have?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `FragmentManager` to create a `FragmentTransaction` Normally you can have 2 animations one for the slide in of the new and one for the slide out of the old I'll use yours for both, like this:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.setCustomAnimations(a, a);
tx.replace(oldFragmentReference, newFragmentReference);
tx.commit();
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I cannot call the getFragmentManager? what could be possibly wrong??

Comment: Ok what is the super class ? should be fine if you do it from Activity. If you are before HoneyComb though you need to extend FragmentActivity instead.